# Using pthreads mutex and condition variables

Tags: c, pthreads, mutex

The problem I am seeking some help for is written in point no. 7. Before that, I describe the structure of my code.

1. From `main()`, two threads thread1 and thread2 are created and initialized to two functions `fun1()` and `fun2()` respectively.
2. I have a mutex named `lock_mutex` and condition variables named `cond1`, `cond2`, `cond3` and `cond4.`
3. I have global boolean variables `var1`, `var2`, `var3` and `var4` all initialized to false.
4. `fun1()` is like the following:

   ```
   void fun1(){
   while(1){
   pthread_mutex_lock(&lock_mutex);
   while(var1 is false)
       pthread_cond_wait(&cond1,&lock_mutex);
   //do some work
   set var3 = true;
   pthread_cond_signal(&cond3);
   set var1=false;
   pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock_mutex);
   }
   }
   ```
5. `fun2()` is as following:

   ```
   void fun2(){
   while(1){
   pthread_mutex_lock(&lock_mutex);
   while(var2 is false)
       pthread_cond_wait(&cond2,&lock_mutex);
   //do some work
   set var4 = true;
   pthread_cond_signal(&cond4);
   set var2=false;
   pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock_mutex);
   }
   }
   ```
6. There are functions in my code which hold `lock_mutex`, do some work and signal `cond1` and `cond2` when appropriate, like this (each is a separate function):

function A:

```
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock_mutex);
    //do some work
    set var1= true;
    pthread_cond_signal(&cond1);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock_mutex);
```

function B:

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&lock_mutex);
//do some work
set var2= true;
pthread_cond_signal(&cond2);
pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock_mutex);
```

function C:

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&lock_mutex)
//do some work
while(var3 is false)
pthread_cond_wait(&cond3,&lock_mutex);
//do more work
set var3=false;
pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock_mutex);
```

function D:

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&lock_mutex)
//do some work
while(var4 is false)
pthread_cond_wait(&cond4,&lock_mutex);
//do more work
set var4= false;
pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock_mutex);
```

7.`fun1()` and `fun2()` are signaled repeatedly by function A and function B. I expect `fun1()` and `fun2()` to call function C and function D each time they are signaled.

But `fun1()` and `fun2()` are being woken up only for the first time. After that, they enter the while loop, acquire the lock and wait for the signal indefinitely and don't wake up despite signaling.

I am not being able to understand the cause of this problem and would be very thankful to any suggestion. If any good debugging techniques/tools for this kind of program is available, kindly refer me to them too.

With many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like a deadlock.

If one thread acquires a mutex lock and then waits for a variable to get set, 
how does another thread acquire the mutex lock to set the variable?

Comment: I would say check http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/iseries/v5r1/ic2924/index.htm?info/apis/users_76.htm, they use a series of printf statements to track the flow of the code, perhaps this approach will shed light on what is happening

Answer (score 1):

The answer to Mr. Graves's question is that pthread_cond_wait automatically unlocks the mutex while blocking.

Answer (score 0):

Signaling a condition variable doesn't mean the blocking thread acquires the lock and starts running immediately, it means it's awakened, and when the scheduler wishes, it will give the blocking thread CPU time.

So, what I think happens here is the following:

- `function B` signals `cond2`.
- `fun2` is awakened, sets `var4` to true, signals `cond4`, sets `var2` to false, releases the mutex.
- `fun2` reacquires the mutex, and rereleases it, waiting on `cond2` for `var2` to become true.
- `function B` gets the mutex, sets `var2` to true, signals `cond2`
- `fun2` is awakened, sets `var4` to true, signals `cond4`, sets `var2` to false, releases the mutex.
- Now two signalings of `cond4` have been collapsed into one.